# Ошибка при испольовании функции toupper

Tags: c, c++

Привет всем, сейчас разбирался с библиотекой cctype в Си и наткнулся на функцию toupper, которая меняет символы из нижнего регистра в верхний.
Вот написал небольшой код (не использовал char, как в примере):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()  {
string str1;
    cout << "Введите Y или N для дальнейшей работы: ";
    do
    {
        str1 = cin.get();
        str1 = toupper(str1);
    }
    while(str1 != "Y" || str1 != "N")
    if (str1 == "Y") { cout << "Спасибо, что ввели: " << "str1" << endl; }
    else {cout << "попробуйте еще раз" << endl;}
}
```

Мне выдает компилятор ошибку:

> prog.cpp:12:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘toupper(std::string&)’
>              str1 = toupper(str1);

не могу понять, в чем дело - ведь вроде все правильно написал в 12-о строке.
Помогите исправить.

Comment: @Hamsternik, а разве это не Сишный toupper()?

Ему нужно передавать один символ, а не std::string.

Comment: Да, точно! Оказывается, нужно просто было написать:
str1 = toupper(str1[0]);
Только вот проблемка в том теперь, что программа работает вечно...

Comment: Ну у вас снова ошибка с cin.get(); Очищайте входной поток после использования

Comment: @Hamsternik, к тому же какая-то странная логика - зачем использовать std::string для того, чтобы каждый раз при вводе нового символа переписывать её содержимое, да ещё и применять к этому Си-шную функцию. Можно же взять переменную типа char, вводить каждый раз новый символ в неё, и просто добавлять его к вашей строке str1, а на выходе вывести её.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подключить заголовочный файл `algorithm` и воспользоваться его благами в виде функции `std::transform`:

```
#include <algorithm>

...
string str1;

getline(cin, str1);
std::transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), toupper);

...
```

---

Что можно сделать конкретно в вашем случае:

1. Как я написал в комментарии выше, добавить переменную типа `char` для вводимого символа (вы же, как я понял, формируете строку из одиночных символов);
2. Добавлять при каждом новом вводе этот символ к вашей строке `str1`
3. Немного поменять цикл

---

```
char c = '\0';
cout << "Введите Y или N для дальнейшей работы: ";

while(1)
{
    c = cin.get();
    c = toupper(c);

    if (c == 'Y') 
    {
        cout << "Спасибо, что ввели: " << str1 << endl; 
        break;
    }

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    str1 = str1 + c;
}
```

Comment: А разве не надо писать так? 
std::transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(); str1.begin(), ::toupper);

Comment: И да - так можно писать, просто я хочу понять, в чем проблема в моем варианте? Вроде же все верно записано...

Comment: 1. Ваша запись принципиально отличается от моей только наличием '::', т. е. оператора разрешения области видимости, но в данном случае это не критично, можно оставить его, а можно убрать.
2. Если смотреть в документацию, то там не написано, что toupper принимает аргумент типа std::string, поэтому проблема в этом.

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Все таки свой велосипед не всегда хорошо, особенно когда это уже непонятно что :)

Comment: И все-таки у меня не работает первоначальный вариант, где не используется "::" перед toupper.

Comment: Странно <cctype> вы подключили, должно работать и так и так, но возможно есть какие-то дополнительные тонкости

Answer (score 2):

Функция из C принимает int-значение (в которое неявно конвертируется из char-элемента). Потому вам нужно брать указатель на буфер (метод c_str() ) и в цикле обходить всю строку.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

Для std::string присмотритесь сюда:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/toupper/